# Can ssh connected computer control the source

Tags: ssh

If i ssh to some remote computer

```
ssh@hisip
fingerprint is sha256:xxxxx`
then continue (y/n) yes
```

can the remote computer later control my source computer?

Also is there any risk if i connect to a untrusted ssh from a middlemen trusted ssh connection through my source computer ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're simply accepting the way that destination server authorizes itself as the original server.

For example if somebody would try to spoof the IP/Domain that you are using, then you could find that attempt of attack, by verifying the fingerprint, to make sure that this is the same server, that you have accepted previously.

In simpler words, once you have connected to the server one time, your source server will make sure it is the same machine every time.

Comment: Also is there any risk if i connect to the "untrusted"  from a middlemen trusted ssh connection through my source computer ?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I meant. Im A, i ssh -> B. now from B's terminal i ssh -> C.  So A is completely safe ? even if C somehow attacks its ssh source i.e B ?

Comment: Yes, it's safe as long as you don't use passwords directly in bash terminal